# Select Editor editorParams populate values from array in textfile?

Tags: tabulator

I am using Tablulator v4.1. I am creating an interface for our pharmacy organization so a member can change the meeting information without doing any coding. One field is the meeting room location which is a select editor.

Is it possible to populate the values of editorParams with a path to an array stored in a different text file? Something like:

```
{title:"Room", field:"room", editor:"select", editorParams:{"/textfiles/roomvalues.txt"}},
```

I can then create another table to add/edit the possible room choices.

This code is what I currently use.

```
{title:"Room", field:"room", editor:"select", editorParams:{
     values:{
         "A":"Room A", 
         "B":"Room B", 
         "C":"Room C"}
 }},
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function into the ***values*** property that can then return an array of values that you can load from elsewhere

```
{title:"Room", field:"room", editor:"select", editorParams:{
    values:function(cell){

        //lookup values from data source

        return values;
}}},
```